# How to save two IPS in single network card

Tags: linux, centos-6

I am using `centos 6.6` and going to configure single network card with two IP address.

My configuration look like this

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts

ifcfg-eth0

DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
IPV6INIT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="cfad5e20-0427-4b8f-a291-4e9bf6cc9ff4"
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME="System eth0"
HWADDR=00:0C:29:4A:DA:ED
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
LAST_CONNECT=1433864544

ifcfg-eth0:1

DEVICE="eth0:1"
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR="00:0c:29:4a:da:ed"
IPADDR="10.0.0.20"
NETMASK="255.0.0.0"
BROADCAST=10.255.255.255
ONBOOT="yes"
```

After restarting my PC I'm not able to view `eth0:1` IP address through ifconfig command.

Comment: quick response would be appreciate

Answer (score 1):

> After restarting my PC I'm not able to view eth0:1 IP address through **ipconfig** command.

Ipconfig is a Windows command, you are probably thinking of *ifconfig*. Still, *ifconfig* is an obsolete command: you should try instead

```
       ip link show
       ip addr show
```

and check whether it shows up now. If it does (I do not have a CentOS system to check your config script, so I do not know whether there are other errors), it is exactly the reason why ifconfig is considered obsolete, and has been superseded by the *iproute2* suite.

Comment: Sorry it's my typing mistake it's not ipconfig it's ifconfig any how thanks for giving response.